# How to remove single line between two lines

Tags: awk, sed, python3

I have milllions of records in a file which look like this

```
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2553,24" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.58   5.39  82.09 237
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2555,20" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.72   5.58  82.05 237
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2557,20" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.75   5.62  82.11 170
grep "2557,21" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.34   5.58  82.13 120
grep "2558,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.2   5.57  82.19 120
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2560,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.69   5.62  82.25 160
grep "2561,23" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.74   5.60  82.30 120
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2560,24" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.38   5.54  82.30 170
echo "NEW Cell"
```

Now I want to delete the line with "grep" on the condition that it is the ONLY line between the lines containing "New Cell". 
That is if there is one line of grep in between new cell, then this line should be deleted.

How to do this?

My output should look like,

```
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2557,20" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.75   5.62  82.11 170
grep "2557,21" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.34   5.58  82.13 120
grep "2558,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.2   5.57  82.19 120
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2560,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.69   5.62  82.25 160
grep "2561,23" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.74   5.60  82.30 120
```

Comment: add your expected output for given sample for clarity.. and show your own efforts to solve it..

Comment: I am new to sed dont know how to go ahead

Comment: imo, sed is not suitable for this, especially if you are new to it.. easy to do with GNU awk.. and you've tagged python which I suppose you know how to use.. so make an attempt in that language... don't expect others to do entire work for you

Comment: Looks like you are also deleting some lines with `echo "NEW Cell"`. What is the logic with this? The output prints the first one, but removes the last.

Comment: @Sundeep That's a question of where you come from, whether this is easier with `sed` or `awk`. For a programmer used to dealing with variables and conditional structures you may be right, but others may find the `sed` answer with only 2 addresses and 4 commands easier then the lengthy `awk` code. It's a different mind set, so don't be too quick with your judgement.

Comment: @Philippos of course, if you are sed expert, you could do as you posted in your answer :) it my personal experience and I qualified it with imo.. h,d,x etc are too cryptic for me and again imo not easy to understand and change it at a later date.. my personal preference is GNU awk or perl for such problems... `awk -v RS='echo' -v ORS= '/grep.*grep/{print RS $0}'`

Comment: @Sundeep Sorry, didn't meant to criticize your comment, just to widen your mind: I'm not talking about `sed` experts, but of the average non-programmer. They are not used to programming commands, variables and syntax, but to keyboard shortcuts (much like the `sed` commands) and a clipboard (much like the `sed` hold space). According to my experience, to those people, `sed` is less hard to understand than `awk` or `perl`, if you don't teach it like a programming language, but like "think of how to select certain lines and what to do with them".

Comment: I took it as discussion only :) shortcuts/clipboard is good analogy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`AWK`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==n{ if (/NEW Cell/) { f=0 } else print r ORS gr }
     /NEW Cell/{ f=1; n=NR+2; r=$0; next }
     f && n-NR==1 && /^grep /{ gr=$0; next }1' file
```

- `/NEW Cell/{ f=1; n=NR+2; r=$0; next }` - on encountering line with `NEW Cell`

  - `f=1` = set active flag `f=1`
  - `n=NR+2` - set `n` as maximum number of the following lines to be processed (2 next lines)
  - `r=$0` - capturing the line
  - `next` - jump to next record
- `f && n-NR==1 && /^grep /` - on encountering the 2nd line (ensured by `n-NR==1`) that starts with `grep` keyword

  - `gr=$0; next` - capturing `grep` line and jump to next(third) record
- `NR==n{ if (/NEW Cell/) { f=0 } else print r ORS gr }` - on encountering 3rd crucial line (ensured by `NR==n`)

  - `if (/NEW Cell/) { f=0 }` - if the 3rd line under processed section contains `NEW Cell` - reset current processing with `f=0`(all previously captured lines are skipped)
  - `else print r ORS gr` - otherwise print all previously captured lines

---

The output:

```
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2557,20" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.75   5.62  82.11 170
grep "2557,21" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.34   5.58  82.13 120
grep "2558,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.2   5.57  82.19 120
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2560,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.69   5.62  82.25 160
grep "2561,23" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.74   5.60  82.30 120
```

Comment: Hi I have just now created the account on this platform. Getting familiar with the website.

Comment: Pls explain about the initial part too. awk 'NR==n{ if (/NEW Cell/) { f=0 } else print r ORS gr }

Comment: @geet, I have posted a verbose explanation. Pay attention and read attentively

Answer (score 2):

Compact solution with `sed`:

```
sed '/NEW Cell/!{H;d;};x;/\n.*\n/!d'
```

If the line does not contain `NEW Cell` execute `H` to append the line to the hold space and `d` to stop processing for that line.

So further commands are only applied to `NEW Cell` lines: The `x` exchanges pattern space and hold space, thus the line is now in the hold space and further lines can be appended, while the pattern space contains everything appended to the last `NEW Cell` line. Your requirement is that there is more than one line between the `NEW Cell` lines, so there must be at least two newlines in the pattern space. If not, delete it without output: `/\n.*\n/!d`.

Comment: Thank you Philippos and everyone for responding to my query. It works fine. I am new to UNIX enviorment. If I want to delete a group that has ONLY two lines begining with grep, then I have to use              sed '/NEW Cell/!{H;d;};x;/\n.*\n *\n/!d'

Comment: that is two lines beginining with grep and BOUNDED by "NEW Cell" .

Comment: Exactly, execept that it's dot-star, not whitespace-star (the dot stands for "any character" and the follwoing star means "repeated any number of times", so `.*` will match every possible line.

Answer (score 1):

With rudimentary `awk`...

Version 1 will only delete `grep` lines which follows OP's description:

```
awk '/^grep/ { if (f) { if (length(s) > 0) { print s; s="" } print } \
     else { f=1; s=$0 } } ! /^echo/ { print; f=0 } \
     ! /^echo/ && ! /^grep/ { print }' inputfile
```

Version 2 will delete solo `grep` lines as well as preceding non-grep line which follows OP's sample output:

```
awk '/^grep/ { if (f) { if (length(s) > 0) { print s; s="" } print } \
    else { f=1; s=s "\n" $0 } } /^echo/ { s=$0; f=0 } \
    ! /^echo/ && ! /^grep/ { print }' inputfile
```

Readable form of version 2...

```
/^grep/ { 
   if (found) {  # found==true : already encountered first grep line
       if (length(save) > 0) {
          print save
          save=""
       }
       print
   } else {
       found=1
       save=save "\n" $0  # append the first grep line to saved preceding line
   }
}

/^echo/ { 
    save=$0  # save this line for possible later printing
    found=0
}

# print anything else
! /^echo/ && ! /^grep/ { print }
```

This long form can be run by putting the contents in a file (e.g. `awkfile`) and `awk -f awkfile inputfile`.

Comment: Thanks I did not work. Gave me output like this awk -f awkfile TESTF >OUTPUTAWK
awk: awkfile: line 7: syntax error at or near else
awk: awkfile: line 11: extra '}'
awk: awkfile: line 11: syntax error at or near end of line

Comment: You put the long form in a file? I can tell just by looking at it that there are no extra `}` and I just did it myself to be sure and it's fine. Check your copy/paste for errors. Also, try the one-liner version which doesn't require a file and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks it worked, But it removed the "Start " and End lines and "All done" which I wanted

Comment: Like echo "Start 2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF 2496 2638"
echo "dimensions 9247 49"

Comment: What are those lines? They're not in your question.

Comment: I took a guess at what you're talking about and updated the answer. You gotta put all these details in your question.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But kindly explain the commands.

Comment: I have beging and ending lines as echo "Start 2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF 2496 2638"
echo "dimensions 9247 49"       followed by LINES posted above and in the END, the file looks like, echo "All Done"
echo "End 2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF 2496 2638"
echo "Start 2A25.20090309.64458.7.HDF 6496 6750"

Comment: My solution is a very simple awk script which is mostly control structures which are common to many languages. I expanded it to make it readable and I commented the few lines that might not be obvious. I suggest you do some reading on awk fundamentals. If you then have specific questions I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '
/\n.+\n/{
    printf("%s%s", RS, $0);
}' RS='echo "NEW Cell"\n' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

1. `RS='echo "NEW Cell"\n'` - `RS` is the input record separator, by default a newline. Now it is changed to the `echo "NEW Cell"\n`, thus, all occurrences of this string will be removed and all characters between them became the record item.
2. `/\n.+\n/{` - only for records that match to this pattern - newline, one or more characters, newline. So, it matches only to multiline records, the single line record doesn't match, because it has only one `\n`.
3. `printf("%s%s", RS, $0);` - prints the record, preceded by the `RS` (`echo "NEW Cell"\n`).

**Output**

```
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2557,20" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 19.75   5.62  82.11 170
grep "2557,21" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.34   5.58  82.13 120
grep "2558,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.2   5.57  82.19 120
echo "NEW Cell"
grep "2560,22" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.69   5.62  82.25 160
grep "2561,23" out.2A25.20090308.64436.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.74   5.60  82.30 120
```